# Is a String array subclass of an Object array?

Tags: java, arrays, collections

I think I'm missing something basic here. Any explanation or pointers to previously asked questions will be very helpful.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class St {

    public static void bla(Object[] gaga) {
            gaga[0] = new Date(); // throws ArrayStoreException
        System.out.println(gaga[0]);
    }

    public static void bla(List<Object> gaga) {
        System.out.println(gaga.get(0));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            String[] nana = { "bla" };
        bla(nana); // Works fine

        List<String> bla1 = Arrays.asList(args);
        bla(bla1); // Wont compile

            System.out.println(new String[0] instanceof Object[]); // prints true
            System.out.println(nana.getClass().getSuperclass().getSimpleName()); // prints Object
    }

}
```

So, it seems like a `List<String>` is not a subclass of a `List<Object>` but a `String[]` is a subclass of `Object[]`.

Is this a valid assumption? If so, why? If not, why?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Java arrays are covariant](http://www.pmg.csail.mit.edu/papers/popl97/node19.html), i.e. they allow `Object[] foo = new String[2];`. But this doesn't mean they are subclasses. `String[]` is a subclass of `Object` (although `instanceof` returns true, `String[].class.getSuperclass()` returns `Object`)

Comment: From @maerics comment below -- the `new String[0] instanceof Object[]` returns true. So, String[] is a type of Object and a type of Object[] and a type of CharSequence[] etc. Correct?

Comment: @Kal that appears to be a special case to cover the covariance. See my update

Comment: `String[] >1 Object` seems to be a bug, I cannot get `getSuperClass` to return an Array for *any* other type either. But http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.10.3 seems to say that is what it should be

Answer (score 6):

Yes, your assumption is valid. As said by @Bozho arrays are covariant, whereas generic collections (such as generic List) are not covariant.

Covariance in arrays is risky:

```
String[] strings = new String[] { "a", "b" }
Object[] objects = strings;
objects[0] = new Date();  // <-- Runtime error here 
String s = strings[0];
s.substring(5, 3);        // ????!! s is not a String
```

The third line fires a runtime exception. If it weren't firing this exception then you could get a `String` variable, `s`, that references a value that is not a `String` (nor a subtype thereof): a `Date`.

Comment: Thanks .. I have never seen the ArrayStoreException before.

Answer (score 4):

```
(new String[0] instanceof Object[]) // => true
```

Answer (score 3):

You are correct. Array types are covariant in Java by design, but a `Foo<Sub>` is-not-a `Foo<Super>`.

Answer (score 2):

> String[] is a subclass of Object[]

Correct, see [4.10.3 Subtyping among Array Types](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.10.3):

> If S and T are both reference types, then S[] >1 T[] iff S >1 T.

Since `String >1 Object` so `String[] >1 Object[]`

That is, `String[]` is a **direct subtype** of `Object[]`

> Object >1 Object[]

Therefor `Object > String[]`; `String[]` is a (indirect?) **subtype** of `Object`

No such relationship exists for generics, so `List<String>  > List<Object>` is not true.

Now, consider the following simple example:

```
import java.util.*;

class G {
    interface I {
    void f();
    }
    class C implements I {
    public void f() {}
    }

    void allF(List<I> li) {
    for (I i : li) { i.f(); }
    }

    void x(List<C> lc) {
    allF(lc);
    }
}
```

It does not compile, because `x` is invoking `allF` with a `List<C>` which is *not* a `List<I>`. To be able to use `List<C>` the signature has to change slightly:

```
void allF(List<? extends I> li) {
```

Now it compiles. Informally, `li` is a `List` of *some* type that extends/implements I. So `List<C>` is *assignable to* `List<? extends I>`. What you can do with such a list is limited. Essentially, you can read/access it but cannot `write/modify` it.

Comment: Umm ... subtype and subclass mean different things.

Comment: @StephenC, for classes subtyping is same as subclassing, if I am reading [4.10.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2). I guess the correct response would be "Arrays are not classes so they cannot have subclass relationship but String[] *is* a *sybtype* of Object[]". Is that what you are hinting?